# Serially Rename multiple files at once

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

There are multiple files (.mp4) in a directory that begin with different names. I want to add serial number as a prefix, keeping their previous name unchanged. What's wrong with my coding?

```
@echo off

set i=1
for %%f in (*.mp4) do call :renameit "%%f"

goto done

:renameit
ren "*.mp4" "%i% *.mp4"
set /A i+=1

:done
```

Give any other suggestion with 'explanation' as I am new to batch programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to change files names then first build the list and then enumerate it like

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b *.mp4') do .......
   ```

   In case you may have files that start with `;` character use `"eol=* delims="`
2. The subroutine parameters are accessed as `%1`, `%2` and so on:

   ```
   ren %1 "%i% %~nx1"
   ```

   Note the `~nx` prefix of `%1` gets the actual name+extension of the file.
   Also note that I didn't quote `%1` because it's passed quoted, but when in doubt use `"%~1"`

Comment: Can we use ***token=*** also, instead of ***delims=*** ? @wOxxOm

Comment: @ShubhRohilla, no, and there's no need for that. Although you can use `tokens=*` but it will fail on files with two or more sequential spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@echo off

set i=1
for %%f in (*.mp4) do call :renameit "%%f"

goto done

:renameit
ren %1 "%i% %~1"
set /A i+=1

:done
```

@wOxxOm's `"%i% %~nx1"` is more general, but in this specific situation because we get the file names from `for %%f in (*.mp4)` we can get by with just `"%i% %~1"`. The modifiers are documented in the help for 'for', see `for /?`.